# notify user, on image sbmission , before submit rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><%=  (I18n.t 'user.form.your_avatar')%></label>
    <div class="push">
        <%= image_tag @user.avatar, class: 'img-avatar' if @doctor.avatar.attached?  %>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <%= form.file_field :avatar, class: 'custom-file-input', data: { toggle: 'custom-file-input' } %>
        <%= form.label :avatar, I18n.t('doctor.form.choose_new_avatar'), class: 'custom-file-label' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to inform user once he chooses image `image uploaded successfully` , before submitting the data. How can this be handled? Any logic?

Comment: You need to add a 'change' event in jQuery on the fileupload-field and send the data via post to the backend.

Comment: I have many fields in that form, I should store the image separately??? I actually want the notification before image stored in database, all the data will be submitted once I click on submit, but for image, Notify if the image is selected successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Then you just need a little jQuery script to add a notification after an image was chosen.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (_e) {
        alert("You've added an image!");
    });
});
```